# Scala syntax problems in for comprehension statement

Tags: scala

Is it possible to make an if statement in a for block?

I have the following:

```
val process = for {
  stepIds <- processTemplateDTO.getProcessStepTemplateIds(processTemplateId)
  allApprovedProcessTemplates <- processTemplateDTO.getApprovedProcessTemplates(clientId) //Get all approved process templates
  processTemplate <- processTemplateDTO.getProcessTemplate(processTemplateId, clientId) // Get the Process Template
  prerequisites <- getProcessTemplateForEdit(processPrerequisitesDTO.getProcessPrerequisiteProcessTemplateIdsByProcessTemplateId(processTemplateId), clientId)
  postConditions <- getProcessTemplateForEdit(processPostConditionsDTO.getProcessPostConditionProcessTemplateIdsByProcessTemplateId(processTemplateId), clientId)
  approvedProcessTemplate <- processTemplateDTO.getProcessTemplate(processTemplate.get.approveprocess, clientId)
  if (processTemplate.get.trainingsprocess.isDefined) {
    trainedProcessTemplate <- processTemplateDTO.getProcessTemplate(processTemplate.get.trainingsprocess.get, clientId)
  }
```

And I only want to call the `processTemplateDTO.getProcessTemplate` if `processTemplate.get.trainingsprocess.isDefined` is true

is this possible?

Thanks

also tried this way:

```
trainedProcessTemplate <- {
        if (processTemplate.get.trainingsprocess.isDefined) {
          processTemplateDTO.getProcessTemplate(processTemplate.get.trainingsprocess.get, clientId)
        } else {
          None
        }
      }
```

**UPDATE**

[image]

```
  trainedProcessTemplate <- Nil
    _ = if (processTemplate.get.trainingsprocess.get != null) {
      processTemplateDTO.getProcessTemplate(processTemplate.get.trainingsprocess.get, clientId)
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible to use `if` block in `for` block, there are two ways

```
 for {
     a <- somework1 // returns boolean
     b <- somework2 if(a)
  } yield (a, b) //anything you like
```

or you can try

```
for {
     a <- somework1 // returns boolean
     b <- if(a) somework2 else somework3
  } yield (a, b) //anything you like
```

In 2nd way you have to give else block as well because without that it will return `Any`

Hope this helps!

Comment: I tried the first one, buth the `somework` is called the if is not called bevore the somework has been called

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more, sorry but i am not able to understand the comment.

Comment: I want thet somework2 is only called if the if statement returns true.... but it is called on false as well

Comment: Try the 2nd solution
PS: you will need the else block as well.

Comment: I tried this 'trainedProcessTemplate <- if (processTemplate.get.trainingsprocess.isDefined) processTemplateDTO.getProcessTemplate(processTemplate.get.trainingsprocess.get, clientId) else ""'  But Now I got an error. value flatMap is not a member of Object

Comment: The return type of if block and else block should be the same. I mean if you are returning "" in else block then if block should be returning String as well.

Comment: hm but I want to return an empty value

Comment: what is the return type of IF block.

Comment: Future[Option[ProcessTemplatesModel]]

Comment: then its simple in ELSE block just return Future(None) or Future.successful(None)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, It is possible.
You can see the below code for reference -

```
    val list = List(1,2,3,4)
    val result = for {
        id <- list
        _ = if (id < 2) {
         println(s"Hello I am $id")
        }
      } yield id
```

Comment: Thanks that looks better but now I get errors on the following tasks

Comment: I also get such types of exceptions when working with for-comprehension. There are some rules for handling for-comprehension. for example, One of them is 1). if the first line in for-comprehension is a future call, then all the remaining calls on the right side of -> should be in future. Otherwise, It gives result of type Future[Nothing]. I am also trying to understand For-comprehension completely.